# Firedac TFDEventAlerter and Firebird 4.0

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac, firebird-4.0

I am trying to use the Firedac TFDEventAlerter in Delphi 10.4 to handle the events of a Firebird 4.0 database. Is that possible?

With Firebird 2.5 it all works fine, but the same code in combination with Firebird 4.0 does not respond to the post_event().

I have not tried it with Firebird 3.0. I use fbClient 4.0.1.2692

I copied the client application to the server where Firebird4.0 is running, and that works (!). Is it so that the events are using a different port?
I thought, if the client can connect to the database that should be enough.

As Arioch suggested, I took a look at firebird.conf, and see the following:

```
# The TCP Port Number to be used for server Event Notification
# messages.The value of 0 (Zero) means that the server will choose
# a port number randomly.
#
# Per-connection configurable.
#
# Type: integer
#
#RemoteAuxPort = 0
```

So, I suppose, I have to choose a fixed port, and open it in the firewall.

Comment: In general, events work just fine in Firebird 4.0, but I don't use Delphi. Have you tried with Firebird 3.0? Does that work or fail in the same way? Also, which version of fbclient.dll are you using with your application?

Comment: Can it be TCP problems, for example antivirus/firewall? or, if several FB instances running on the same machine at the same time, can they fight over some TCP port used for events subscription ?  read `firebird.conf` of both servers to learn about TCP ports used (or about Windows atom names, if you use XNET protocol instead of TCP)

Answer (score 0):

As the OP [posted elsewhere](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support/c/7dcjwN3fYcg/m/BmSUOdHBBQAJ):

> It had nothing to do with the version.
> The FB4.0 was running on
> another server, and  I had to adjust teh firewall for the port the
> events where sent ( configured in firebird.config )